# giving custom autosuggestion for uitextfield iphone

Tags: iphone, autocomplete, uitextfield, autosuggest

I have to implement a custom autosuggestion for UITextField>
I have an array of words and when I start typing in a textfield then all words similar to the typed text should appear as auto suggestion, like normal auto suggestion in ios but more than one word. And When I tap on one of them it should trigger an event. I know how to done this with a tableview anybody know a method to done this with ios's look and feel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this purpose I used the project linked below:
http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/autocompletiontableview

Answer (score 3):

A sexy look for a autocomplete:

UITextField + UITextFieldDelegate
http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=wepopover

Using UITableView you keep the data and apply an predicate on:

- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string

[image]

I didn't attach source code because isn't general and might confuse you.

Answer (score 1):

Make an `array` of `NSString`, and search the typed string in `UITextfield` delegate method `textChanged:`, then print strings in a `tableView`.

In fact this will work like a `UISearchBar`.