# IOS - UITextField [Search in sqlite database during typing]

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

First i will obtain the database in an NSArray so it is not sqlite issue.

My question is about detecting the word, simply i need to auto-complete word from an NSArray during the typing.

I found some tutorials which talking about

```
[UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification - addObserver .. etc]
```

but not describing it clearly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10550163/1059705 http://stackoverflow.com/q/11344461/1059705 kindly see these links that might be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement `UITextfield` action method `Editing Changed` in your .m file and then implement following code for search and filter array according you typp in it.

```
 NSString *match = textField.text; 
 NSMutableArray *listFiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", match];
 listFiles = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[YOURARRAYNAME filteredArrayUsingPredicate:sPredicate]];
 NSLog(@"%@",listFiles);

 // following array gives you sorted array
    NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray: [listFiles sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];

    NSLog(@"%@",sortedArray);
```

Comment: Perfect, THANKS A MILLION .. its working like a dream.
now when i am typing i can see the array in the debugger, how i can make the auto complete thing inside the textfield ??

Comment: I dont know exact about autocomplete. but if above answer is working for you than you can accept and upward th answer.